# apache nifi 1.12.0 shows invalid component while adding kylo processor

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

[image]

when am trying to add kylo processor .nars in nifi, it will show as in image with comment

> Missing processor validated aginist any property is invalid and
> processor is of type com.thinkbiganalytics.v2.spark.ExecuteSparkJob
> but this is not a valid processor type

any help appreciable thanks in advance

Comment: this  is due to an error in  processor code .fixed it